# Save Credentials in a Session

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, pdfkit, splinter

I am trying to use pdfkit to make a visual backup of our company wiki. I am running into trouble since the website requires the user to be logged in to use. I developed a script using splinter that logs into the company wiki, but when pdfkit executes, it returns the log in page. PDFkit must open a different session in that case. How would I be able to find out when credentials (cookies) are needed to access the pages on my site, and save them as a variable so I can grab these screen shots?

I am using python 2.7.8 splinter, requests and pdfkit

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.visit('https://companywiki.com')
browser.find_by_id('login-link').click()
browser.fill('os_username', 'username')
browser.fill('os_password', 'password')
browser.find_by_name('login').click()
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url("https://pagefromcompanywiki.com", "c:/out.pdf")
```

I also found the following script which will log me in and save credentials, but I'm not sure how to tie it in to what I am trying to do.

```
import requests
import sys
EMAIL = ''
PASSWORD = ''
URL = 'https://company.wiki.com'
def main():
    session = requests.session(config={'verbose': sys.stderr})
    login_data = {
        'loginemail': EMAIL,
        'loginpswd': PASSWORD,
        'submit': 'login',
    }
    r = session.post(URL, data=login_data)
    r = session.get('https://pageoncompanywiki.com').

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this task are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log in with your Splinter `browser`, the site sends you [HTTP cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) that identify your authorized session, and `browser` remembers them for further requests.

But PDFKit knows nothing about your `browser`. It just passes the URL you gave it down to the underlying [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) tool, which then fetches the page with its own default settings.

What you need to do is transfer cookies from `browser` to wkhtmltopdf. Thankfully, it’s easy to connect Splinter and PDFKit in this way:

```
options = {"cookie": browser.cookies.all().items()}
pdfkit.from_url("https://pagefromcompanywiki.com", "c:/out.pdf", options=options)
```

Comment: This ended up working. Thank you for the help. However it only screen capped the top of the page. Any idea if there is a way to set parameters, or ensure it screen shots the entire page?

Comment: @ChaseRaab Not sure, sorry. Consult the [list of wkhtmltopdf options](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) — all of them can be passed via pdfkit’s `options` dictionary, as explained in [pdfkit docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit). If this doesn’t help, try asking a separate question about that.

Answer (score -1):

You have to handle cookies:

```
class CookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar):
    def _cookie_from_cookie_tuple(self, tup, request):
        name, value, standard, rest = tup
        version = standard.get('version', None)
        if version is not None:
            version = version.replace('"', '')
            standard["version"] = version
        return cookielib.CookieJar._cookie_from_cookie_tuple(self, tup, request)
```

and you need an opener as well

```
def getOpener(self):
    handlers = []   
    cj = CookieJar();
    cj.set_policy(cookielib.DefaultCookiePolicy(rfc2965=True))
    cjhdr = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)
    handlers.append(cjhdr)                                             
    return urllib2.build_opener(*handlers)
```

and the you would do something like

```
urlHandle = self.getOpener().open(request)
```

Comment: Is there any documentation you can offer me that would help me understand the function of this?